# Using a try catch statement to only allow a user to input an integer into a textbox on Button Click event

Tags: c#, wpf, click

Trying to figure out how I can use a try catch statement so that when I click the button to output whether a number is odd or even, an error message will be displayed if I enter a string instead of a number! I know how I'd do it using a bool statement to check if the number is a string, was just interested to see how it would work with a try catch or if it's possible! Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int oddOrEven = 0;


        try
        {
             oddOrEven = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumber.Text);
        }

        catch
        {
            tbkOutput.Text = "You must enter a number, please try again";
        }

        if (oddOrEven % 2 == 0)
        {
            tbkOutput.Text = "Number is even";

        }
        else
        {
            tbkOutput.Text = "Number is odd";
        }


    }
```

Comment: It is considered a bad practice to use an exception to drive the flow of your program. By the way, as it stands your program after catching the exception continue and go to test `oddOrEven=0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't let exceptions determine program flow. There is no point doing that here when you have functions like `int.TryParse`:

```
int output = 0;

if (int.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, out output)) {
    // its a number
}
else {
    // it isn't a number
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't really implement any logic based on try catch, maybe consider using TryParse

```
    int oddOrEven = 0; 
    if(!Int32.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, out oddOrEven))
    {
        tbkOutput.Text = "You must enter a number, please try again";
        return;
    }
```